# Producer–consumer pattern: wakeup UI thread

Tags: android, ios

How to implement producer–consumer pattern with background thread(s) as producer(s) and UI thread as consumer? In good old C++ I would use a mutex, a conditional variable and a flag and maybe some sort of concurrent queue. Producer thread(s) would put data into the queue, lock the mutex, set the flag, unlock the mutex and then signal the conditional variable.

How do I implement similar pattern with UI thread? Thank you.

Comment: Concurrency implementations are going to vary wildly from iOS to Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI thread cannot sleep under your control, so there's no direct way of doing that. (Good old C++? *Without* a UI thread then, I suppose?)

- First way is to have a producer and a consumer thread, connect them via a [Linked Blocking Queue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) or something similar, and have the consumer thread post [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html)s on the UI thread. But that only makes sense if the consumer thread actually has some meaningful duty to perform, such as collect samples over a period or so, which justifies that it runs independently etc.
- The second way is to have the producer post [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html)s or deliver [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) messages to the UI thread directly, which is more lightweight and suitable if the consumer does not have any heavy (aka UI blocking) tasks to do.